# Get render info from blend file without open it

Tags: python

Im trying to find a way extract render info from blend file (blender 3.1). So I try to use blend_render_info.py but it does not work. I think there are old code and it does not work with blend files from 3.1 version. I downloaded new version of file from here: [**blend_render_info.py**](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/modules/blend_render_info.py) but no luck, I get some error about missing modules. Maybe anybody can help with that for blender 3.1? Or maybe I missing something.